# C# Abstract Class written in a .cs file cannot be accessed from another .cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, abstract-class

I have a abstract class written in a separate .cs file (BmiCalculator.cs)

```
namespace WebApplication1.App_Code
{
    public abstract class BmiCalculator
    {
        public abstract double Calculate(int heightA, int heightB, double weight);
    }
}
```

I am having another class file (CalBmiStd.cs) which is derived from the above class.

```
namespace WebApplication1.App_Code
{
    public class CalBmiStd : BmiCalculator
    {

    }
}
```

However, (in CalBmiStd.cs) in line "public class CalBmiStd : BmiCalculator", "BmiCalculator" is displays in red and it won't let me extend the abstract class.

Any idea to resolve this please?

Comment: What is the error that you're receiving, verbatim?

Comment: I am getting this when built.
The type or namespace name 'BmiCalculator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding project. Or right click on the error and then resolve.

Comment: Tried cleaning and rebuilding project. Didn't work. I am sure this code should work easily. But something is missing. Cannot spot it at the moment.

Comment: They are in the same project and same folder

Comment: Change the Build Action (in the file properties of BmiCalculator.cs) to `Compile`.

Comment: Yoda, I can't see a resolve option on the right-click menu on visual studio when right clicked on the error.

Comment: Might help if we could see your .csproj file. Can you paste it into your question, please?

Comment: Resolved - Changing the Build Action (in the file properties of BmiCalculator.cs) to Compile resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved - Changing the Build Action (in the file properties of BmiCalculator.cs) to Compile resolved the issue.

Thanks to Crowcoder.